# How to pass different data from 2 submit buttons in 1 form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have 2 submit buttons in one form and I want to pass data from the button that is pressed to a the server and then server can set status based on the data given by form action.

I understand the C# part, I'm just not sure with what to do in Html to pass the data from the button to the form action

HTML

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("Create", new{ name})" method="post">
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="Draft" value="Save as draft " />
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="Publish" value="Save and publish" />
 <form>
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name)
{
       if (name== "Draft")
        {
            model.Status = IPublishable._Status.Draft;
        }
        else 
        {
            model.Status = IPublishable._Status.Published;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Comment: is there a way to do this in the same method or is that not possible

Comment: Of course its possible, even an eligant way available to handle this kind of dynamic request.

Comment: We can even use `formData.Keys.FirstOrDefault();` to get submitted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 2 submit buttons in one form and i want to pass data from the
> button that is pressed to a the server and then server can set status
> based on the data given by form action

Well, we can implement that using `IFormCollection` to handle any kind of dynamic request without defining the name and value in form. In fact, we can submit any kind of dynamic data to controller thus, we can retrive value as we posted there. You can do as following:

View:

```
<form action="Create" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Draft" value="Save as draft " />
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Publish" value="Save and publish"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormCollection formData)
    {

        string? submittedButtonValue = formData.Keys.FirstOrDefault();


        if (submittedButtonValue.Contains("Draft"))
        {
            model.Status = IPublishable._Status.Draft;

        }
       else  if (submittedButtonValue.Contains("Publish"))
        {
             model.Status = IPublishable._Status.Published;
        }


    }
```

**Note:** Up to now, we can get all the data and value what we have submitted from the view.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fastest and easiest way is to add a hidden field to your form and then add something to your submit function that gives it an appropriate value (like .js). Then you will need to process that field on your action page.

Comment: Thank you but i dont want to use any js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the dynamic thing,
Just want to inform you can check this as well it's a very simple and clean approach.

I've just created a sample code for you.

```
//Controller side code
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(string Name, string status)
    {
        return Json(status);
    }
}

//View side code


<div>
    <form asp-action="index" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Name" />
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="status" value="1">
            Save as draft
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="status" value="2">
            Save and publish
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here you can see the output

Just copy-paste the code to check yourself.

[image]
[image]